# How to define HTTP filter for GraphQL requests?

Tags: quarkus, microprofile, smallrye

I use [Quarkus 1.6.1.Final](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus) version with GraphQL implementation using [SmallRye GraphQL](https://quarkus.io/guides/microprofile-graphql). My aim is to define logic to check user permissions on *every* request (Query + Mutation) made to `/graphql` endpoint. So, I am trying to find something like jax-rs `ContainerRequestFilter` but for GraphQL. Do you have any ideas on how to do it? I've tried to define `ContainerRequestFilter` but it catches only RestEasy requests but not GraphQL ones.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this myself. It seems like GraphQL directly registers a Vert.X routing call [[1](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/smallrye-graphql/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/smallrye/graphql/runtime/SmallRyeGraphQLRecorder.java)] rather than using Undertow(servlets) or RestEASY(jaxrs). This is so it can do stuff like partial results more easily from what I can tell.

You're going to want to look at intercepting Vert.X requests using the RouteFilter annotation. I've included the link below, but it works a lot like the ContainerRequestFilter from jax-rs. I've copied the sample code from the Quarkus help guide [[2](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#intercepting-http-requests)] to provide a quick example:

```
package org.acme.reactive.routes;

import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;

public class MyFilters {

    @RouteFilter(100) 
    void myFilter(RoutingContext rc) {
       // Put your logic here

       // continue the filtering of the request
       rc.next(); 
    }
}
```

1: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/smallrye-graphql/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/smallrye/graphql/runtime/SmallRyeGraphQLRecorder.java

2: https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#intercepting-http-requests

Comment: I get this Error when I add some logic above the method.

`io.quarkus.runtime.BlockingOperationNotAllowedException: You have attempted to perform a blocking operation on a IO thread. This is not allowed, as blocking the IO thread will cause major performance issues with your application. If you want to perform blocking EntityManager operations make sure you are doing it from a worker thread.`

Comment: This is taking advantage of vert.x to hook into the request chain, so this part should be pretty safe. It sounds like you may have returned a non `Uni` or `Multi` in a later method though, either at the resource or in your Persistence entity repository, when you are using a reactive framework.